# Core data encrypted attributes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, encryption

we want to encrypt some attributes of our entity, but still be able to perform fetches and predicates using the attribute, without the special care for predicates and etc...

person attribute name is encrypted

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like JOHN"];
johns = [persons filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

core data entity

**.h**

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name; // crypted
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * description; // crypted
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * someAtrribute;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation File

@dynamic name;
@dynamic description;
@dynamic someAttribute;

@end
```

- i cannot change @dynamic to @synthesize and implement my custom setter and getter
- i could change the encrypted property to c_name and add a synthesized property name with custom getter and setter, but this won't work on predicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually **can** implement custom accessor methods, read up this [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html).